# Crystal Reports + VS2010 deploy to remote webserver

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, publishing

I made an web application using Crystal Reports for .NET + VS2010 + ASP.NET

In the local IIS, the application works fine.

In the remote server, the page comes blank. If I display the source of the page, the content of the crystal components is in the source.

I read in some sites, I need to put the aspnet_client on the web server but I don't have this folder in my project neither in the publish folder.

How should I do to generate the aspnet_client folder with this components?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) First of all you have to install Crytal Reports Runtime on the server (MSI, 32 or 64 bit depending on server HW)

- [You can download here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

2) then, if the application is not installed into default web site

- Copy aspnet_client folder from c:\inetpub\wwwroot folder to the new website root folder.

or (second one is better)

- Create a virtual directory called aspnet_client that points to c:\inetpub\wwwroot inside the new website